# Есть ли возможность передать 2 значения?

Tags: php

2 страницы. 1 - вопросы, 2 - ответы. Вот у меня есть простой сайт с тестом, ответы передаются через radiobutton (не передаются, ну, короче тип radiobutton, я надеюсь вы поняли), когда по завершении я нажимаю на кнопку для перехода для просмотра правильных ответов. у меня выводится например "1 задание 1 вопрос правильно" Могу ли я как-то сделать так, чтобы у меня передавался также вопрос? Вот так написан вопрос:

```
<div>
<p>1. какой-то вопрос </p>
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="correct">ответ 1.</label></br>
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect">ответ 2.</label></br>
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect">ответ 3.</label></br>
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect"> ответ 4.</label></br>
</div>
```

q[0] - массив для передачи значения правильно или нет

вот так я получаю ответы:

```
<?php
$k = 0; //для подсчета правильных ответов
$r = 10; //количество вопросов (бесполезная, можно было внизу написать просто)
$l = -1; //номер вопроса. -1 потому что если 0, то отсчет почему-то с 2 начинается. (ну поому что я накосячила и не поняла)

if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
if (is_array ($_POST['q'])){
$l = $l + 1;

foreach($_POST['q'] as $value)
{

if ($value=='correct') {
$k =$k + 1;

}
if ($_POST['q']){
$l = $l + 1;
}

echo "Задание 1: Вопрос $l: ", $value, '<br>';

}

echo '<br>', "У вас {$k} правильных ответов из {$r} вопросов", '</br>';
}
}else {
echo "В задании 1 Вы не ответили ни на один вопрос", '<br>';
}
?>//остальное вроде понятно что зачем? Если что, могу поянить..
```

Вот могу ли я как-то написать в `<label>`, не знаю, еще 1 value? (у меня не вышло, я пыталась)) и получить его, чтобы вид выводимой формы был не таким:
`Задание 1: Вопрос 1: incorrect`
А вот таким:
`Задание 1: Вопрос 1: какой-то вопрос, ваш ответ ..., правильный - ...`

Comment: Зачем передавать обратно на сервер вопросы если изначально вопросы генерятся на сервере? Может надо подумать и понять, что массив с вопросами можно получить на сервере при проверке данных от формы?

Comment: u_mulder, да, Вы правы. Я так хотела сделать, но не совсем понялакак. Я имею ввиду, что я вообще без понятия, каким образом можно в эту же строку - эту: <label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="correct">ответ 1.</label></br> запихнуть еще 1 массив. Или это сделать, как предложил SeeNax? Вот я получаю ответ на первый вопрос, он неверный, например, я должна туда передать именно первый вопрос, но таких вопросов много. И что мне делать тогда?

Comment: Я пыталась добавить второй массив к первому, типа: <label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect" name1="w[0]" value1="ответ 4"> ответ 4.</label></br> (простите, может это тупо было изначально даже пытаться, но  я вот с ходу решила написать с минимальными знаниями и по ходу разбираюсь). А для <p> добавить, я если честно вообще забыла передать его -_-

Comment: `номер вопроса. -1 потому что если 0, то отсчет почему-то с 2 начинается.` вы делаете  $l++ вне цикла, а потом ещё раз - в цикле, потому и получается 2

Comment: br3t, Точно. Так и знала, что накосячила.) Я разобралась с выводом ответа, просто добавив эту строчку (ниже). Для p сделаю также и дело с концом:)

Comment: <div><p>1. какой-то вопрос </p>
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="correct">ответ 1.</label></br>
<input type="hidden" name="question[0]" value="1. какой-то ответ">
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect">ответ 2.</label></br>
<input type="hidden" name="question[0]" value="2. какой-то ответ">
<label><input name="q[0]" type="radio" value="incorrect">ответ 3.</label></br>
<input type="hidden" name="question[0]" value="3. какой-то ответ">
</div>

Comment: А нет, не разобралась, показалось)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>1. какой-то вопрос </p>
```

замените на

```html
<input readonly style="border:0" type="text" value="1. какой-то вопрос" name="question">
```

Тогда в $_POST['question'] будет лежать "1. какой-то вопрос". Для input просто измените CSS

Однако я полностью согласен с @u_mulder . Скорее вам стоит подумать над архитектурой приложения.

Comment: SeeNax, благодарю вас! Вы открыли глаза мне на то, что я должна была передавать еще и <p>, я забыла об этом... Я последую вашему совету и попробую разобраться с архитектурой. Я написала в комментарии к ответу u_mulder то, что у меня вызывает вопросы..